# Prove that there exists an $\eta>0$ such that $m(B\setminus A) > \eta$ for non Lebesgue measurable set $E$ and and Lebesgue measurable sets $A, B$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working on prep questions for qualifying exam. I am stuck with the following problem.

Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not Lebesgue measurable. Prove that there exists an $\eta>0$ such that for any two Lebesgue measurable sets $A,B$ satisfying $A \subseteq E \subseteq B$ one has $m(B\setminus A) > \eta$ where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the condition does not hold, show there are measurable $A',B'$ such that $A' \subset E \subset B'$ and $m(B' \setminus A') = 0$ from which we would get that $E$ is measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose otherwise.  Then for each $N$ you can find Lebesgue measurable sets $A_N$ and $B_N$ such that $A_N \subseteq E \subseteq B_N$ and $m(B_N \setminus A_N) < 1/N$.  Without loss of generality we may assume that $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq \dots$ and $B_1\supseteq B_2 \supseteq B_3 \supseteq \dots$ (indeed, if necessary we can replace $A_N$ with $A'_N := A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_N$, which preserves the inclusion $A'_N \subseteq E$ and satisfies $m(A'_N) \geq m(A_N)$.  We can also replace $B_N$ by $B'_N := B_1 \cap \dots \cap B_N$ so that we still have $E \subseteq B'_N$ and $m(B'_N) < m(B_N)$, therefore we have preserved the two necessary conditions, $A'_N \subseteq E \subseteq B'_N$ and $m(B'_N \setminus A'_N) < 1/N$).

Now set $A = \bigcup_{N \geq 1} A_N$ and $B = \bigcap_{N\geq1} B_N$.  We still have $A \subseteq E \subseteq B$, and now we also have $m(B \setminus A) = 0$ by continuity of measure.  This implies that $m^*(B \setminus E) = 0$, where $m^*$ is Lebesgue outer measure.  But then we can write $E = B \setminus (B \setminus E)$, where $B$ is Lebesgue measurable by construction and $B \setminus E$ is also Lebesgue measurable because the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is defined to contain all sets of zero outer measure.  But this implies $E$ is also Lebesgue measurable, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend proving the contrapositive: show that if for any $\eta > 0$ there exists Lebesgue measurable sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \subseteq E \subseteq B$ and $m(B\backslash A) \leq \eta$, then $E$ is measurable.

Hint: all sets of Lebesgue outer measure $0$ are measurable.